# How to count the number of visible columns in a function?

Tags: excel

How do you count the number of visible columns (ignoring hidden columns) in Excel as function within a certain cell range?

Comment: I am afraid that is impossible by using any built-in function. You can achieve that with VBA.

Comment: Not impossible, providing that no unhidden column is less than 0.5 characters in width, which in any case would be so narrow as to be practically hidden by all accounts. The only slight drawback to the formula-based solution would be that it would require the user to force a sheet re-calculation in order to see updated results (changes in column width do not prompt automatic re-calculation). Let me know if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a VBA function for you (since you DID ask for a function, even though you didn't mention VBA as a tag).

```vb
Function outCountVisibleColumns(rRange As Range) As Double

outCountVisibleColumns = 0
For Each Col In rRange.Columns
    If Col.EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then
        outCountVisibleColumns = outCountVisibleColumns + 1
    End If
Next Col

End Function
```

Assuming you put this in your Excel personal workbook, you should be able to put it into cells in any of your spreadsheets like this:

```
=PERSONAL.XLSB!outCountVisibleColumns(C1:J6)
```

Comment: Are you missing a Return outCountVisibleColumns before end function?

Comment: I'm trying to call this function from a cell: like =outCountVisibleColumns (A1: F1)  and getting "#NAME?" error.

Comment: I found I had to name the workbook that the function is saved in, then show an exclamation point, then name the function. Like this: =WorkbookName.xlsb!outCountVisibleColumns(C1:J6)

Comment: And suppose I'd like to refer to a non-active sheet within the same workbook, what's the syntax?

Comment: Also, I'd like the macro function to automatically evaluate itself whenever theres a hidden/visible change among the columns. Application.volatile doesn't seem to work in this case

Comment: @jerryh91 I don't know how to refer to a non-active sheet. I haven't ever done that before! I'm surprised the macro doesn't auto-evaluate. Maybe pressing F9 does it? I can't remember. (I'm mainly a coder!)

Answer (score 0):

A fudge is to have a row in your range of nothing but `1`s, select it with Go To Special, Visible cells only and read off the count from the status bar (assuming you have that set to show Sum).